# Will tf.gradients pass through tf.cond?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to create a pair of recurrent neural networks, say NN<sub>1</sub> and NN<sub>2</sub>, where NN<sub>2</sub> reproduces its output from the previous time step and does not update its weights at the current time step whenever NN<sub>1</sub> outputs a different value from the previous time step.

To do this, I was planning to use `tf.cond()` together with `tf.stop_gradients()`. However, in all toy examples I have run, I cannot get `tf.gradients()` to pass through `tf.cond()`: `tf.gradients()` simply returns `[None]`.

Here is a simple toy example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(5)
y = tf.constant(3)

mult = tf.multiply(x, y)
cond = tf.cond(pred = tf.constant(True),
               true_fn = lambda: mult,
               false_fn = lambda: mult)

grad = tf.gradients(cond, x) # Returns [None]
```

Here is another simple toy example where I define `true_fn` and `false_fn` in `tf.cond()` (still no dice):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(5)
y = tf.constant(3)
z = tf.constant(8)

cond = tf.cond(pred = x < y,
               true_fn = lambda: tf.add(x, z),
               false_fn = lambda: tf.square(y))

tf.gradients(cond, z) # Returns [None]
```

I originally thought that the gradient should flow through both `true_fn` and and `false_fn`, but clearly no gradient is flowing at all. Is this the expected behavior of gradients computed through `tf.cond()`? Might there be a way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the gradients will pass through `tf.cond()`. You just need to use floats instead of integers and (preferably) use variables instead of constants:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(5.0, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable(6.0, dtype=tf.float32)
z = tf.Variable(8.0, dtype=tf.float32)

cond = tf.cond(pred = x < y,
               true_fn = lambda: tf.add(x, z),
               false_fn = lambda: tf.square(y))

op = tf.gradients(cond, z) 
# Returns [<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/cond_1/Add/Switch_1_grad/cond_grad:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(op)) # [1.0]
```